# Worklight Application Runtime error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

We are facing an issue on our PROD environment where it shows the following error message:

[image]

The home page shows that the runtime contains the project files:

[image]

There error on the WAS is:

```
[5/1/15 12:38:29:901 EDT] 0000009f ApplicationMa E 

com.worklight.mgmt.impl.ApplicationManagementImpl getApplicationRuntimeInformation FWLSE0023E: application 'MobileBanking' not found, please redeploy. [project MobileBanking] 
[5/1/15 12:38:29:947 EDT] 0000009f DMAdapter     I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.DMAdapter getAnalysisEngine FFDC1009I: Analysis Engine using data base: /wl62/profiles/node1/properties/logbr/ffdc/adv/ffdcdb.xml 
[5/1/15 12:38:30:069 EDT] 0000009f FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on /wl62/profiles/node1/logs/ffdc/server11_wl_3e94673b_15.05.01_12.38.29.9336586937544274552029.txt com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke 693 
[5/1/15 12:38:30:573 EDT] 00000100 ApplicationSe E   FWLSE3000E: A server error was detected. 
                                 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: FWLSE0023E: application 'MobileBanking' not found, please redeploy. [project MobileBanking] 
        at com.worklight.mgmt.impl.ApplicationManagementImpl.getApplicationRuntimeInformation(ApplicationManagementImpl.java:165) 
        at com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectManagementMXBeanImpl.getApplicationRuntimeInformation(ProjectManagementMXBeanImpl.java:673) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:76) 
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:607) 
        at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:75) 
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor42.invoke(Unknown Source) 
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:607) 
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:279) 
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.ConvertingMethod.invokeWithOpenReturn(ConvertingMethod.java:193) 
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.ConvertingMethod.invokeWithOpenReturn(ConvertingMethod.java:175) 
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(MXBeanIntrospector.java:117) 
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(MXBeanIntrospector.java:54) 
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:237) 
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:138) 
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:252) 
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) 
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) 
        at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335) 
        at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118) 
        at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228) 
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181) 
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.route(CallRouter.java:247) 
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:360) 
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink$IPCConnectorReadCallback.complete(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:602) 
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784) 
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175) 
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217) 
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161) 
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138) 
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204) 
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775) 
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905) 
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
```

We have reinstalled the runtime more than once, and it says successful, we also recycled the dmgr, node, cluser, server and the runtimes and all shows green arrows with successful start up message.

Same WAR file is used on our Dev, QAT and UAT and they all running up with no issues.

Worklight Version 6.2.0.1

WAS version 8.5.5.1

Any help to resolve it, thanks.

Comment: Did you re-deploy the .wlapp after re-deploying the .war file (which does not seem to be the issue anyway)?

Comment: We deployed everything from scratch and the activity log on WL console for the runtime shows that the Adapter and .wlapp are successfully installed. When we tried to reinstall them again, it says that there are no changes on the previous deployment. However, still same error.

Comment: Add trace to the log, maybe it'll produce more information.

Comment: Ok, We will, if we didn't get any extra clue about the issue, we will recycle our DB and most likely uninstall and reinstall the servers. If it didn't work, I will raise a PMR. We should go to PROD by Sunday.

Comment: Sunday has passed. Status?

Comment: Our Server Team has raised PMR on Friday with the troubleshooting process that in progress to save time. PROD deployment has been postponed till end of the week and we are resetting our DB today with full fresh installation. If the problem is solved, PMR will be dropped. If not, at least we saved time to raise the PMR.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to resolve both the application issues and the Worklight service issue. There were multiple pieces that needed to be fixed. For the most part, these issues were a result of having the complexity of the how Worklight implements security. All the environment is up and running now.

Steps we followed to resolve the issue:

- Make sure the exact same configuration are running on both Nodes.
- Make sure that the JVM configuration are matching.
- Review the security configuration on each node (SSL certificate - SLL alias and SSL keystore).